# DNS last dot - root

Tags: dns

saw a video where it said all domains have a dot at the end. so it is http://superuser.com./ this does not work but https://www.google.co.in./ and  http://sel2in.com. do work

though for google need to trust the cert as the name does not match

question : what is the format to include port to this scheme? https://www.google.co.in.:443/ works but not ritemail.blogspot.in.:80/2013/07/funny-lol-pics.html or sel2in.com.:80/g.html

Can someone explain?

Comment: Wikipedia has good info on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name#The_root_of_the_tree_and_DNS

Comment: wow http://uz/ short and worked on firefox

Comment: @techie007 but did not find how to type a address like sel2in.com.:80/g.html

Comment: ports are not part of the FQDN, so treat them as an appendage like the path to the page.

Comment: The ports don't go in the URL when using the .

Answer (score 2):

The DNS root is from the clients perspective, an interesting but meaningless abstraction. there is no pointer to it at all, and other than that its a conceptual container for the TLDs (com, org, gov, edu, mil, etc), it has no other meaning or value to the client. As others have pointed out, DNS administrators do use it for zone transfers and other administration tasks.

also remember that from a strictly DNS standpoint, DNS names run from largest to smallest from left to right, which is the opposite of how we display them in URLs. google would be 'com.google.www' instead of 'www.google.com'.

Certificates do not evaluate ports (or shouldn't). you are establishing the identity of the domain, not a specific service on it.

Comment: yes question was more for understanding than practical use. i figured it out firefox wanted the http part to be before sel2in.com.:80/g.html it works then. not saying the cert is invalid cause of the port but the dot means its no longer an exact match. seems like a minor bug. bug as they allegedly understand the dot but say that https://www.google.co.in/ and https://www.google.co.in./ are not the same

Comment: that's probably the X.509 implementation being very strict regarding input. I agree it may be a bug, but I don't think I'd fix it either.

Answer (score 1):

Much depends on the servers (web and DNS) involved.  A terminating "." implies the DNS root.  A terminating "." is significant for BIND9 DNS server configurations, Windows DNS syntax (I think) doesn't need it.

A similar issue arises with the underscore character.  Windows DNS allows it, but BIND will treat it as an illegal character (though there is a CNAME-based work-around).

Comment: That Frank indicated that it's a meaningless abstraction leads me to believe that he works with Windows DNS servers. (heh)

Answer (score 1):

DNS is a hierarchical distributed database.  So there is one root domain, which is divided into TLDs, which are then divided into domains, which are then divided into subdomains, etc.

A query resolves either to an address or a server that should know.  The server itself can traverse authoritative servers and reply with the ultimate address from whoever is responsible if recursion is enabled on the server.  In this way the distribution aspect of it works.

The final "dot" is always implied even if it's not specified.

I tried pasting `sel2in.com.:80/g.html` in a browser and got an error message saying "Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (sel2in.com.) isn't associated with any program."  I guess the end dot is triggering Firefox into thinking sel2in.com.: is a protocol, i.e. like the `http://` part of the URL.  `http://sel2in.com.:80/g.html` works, though.  **You should always specify the https:// or http:// part of the URL when manually typing URLs to avoid quirks like this, even if the browser strips it after displaying the page.**